# Javascript LARGE 2D array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, 2d

I have a very very large array of 44,000+ objects in a javascript file.

My problem is editing the file is absolutely terrible (especially if I must move each object 1 value in the array).

I've tried a csv file, but I am unable to have the text be my objects. I've considered XML and JSON but I don't see it fixing my editing problems.

I'm hoping for a javascript editor that handles 2d arrays like a table, or essentially anything that will create the array of objects and allow me to edit similarly to a table.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a javascript file as a database? Your problem is likely that the file is just too big for most text editors. You should consider a more effiecient means of storing the data. Sounds like a nightmare to edit/maintain.

Comment: What do you mean "like a table"? Are you saying you're having trouble managing your source code and would like a spreadsheet (or Word table) like layout for your source code so that you can easily edit the individual objects, and also do things like delete a particular one and have all the ones below move up within the array (or all the ones to the right move left)?

Comment: @ Chris 
Believe me, it is a nightmare to edit/maintain. I did this as a little fun project between semesters and my school offered me money to do some stuff with it. The problem, as a first year student, I didn't plan for scalability.

@nnnnnnn
Basically like an excel sheet. Easy to move around values and such in both horizontal and vertical directions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, first of all: what the what? 44,000 objects hardcoded in your source file? Why do you even have 44,000 objects anyway, and can't you generate them somehow?

Anyway...

Assuming I understand your requirement correctly, my suggestion to solve your editing problem but still produce a standard JS script file is to use an Excel spreadsheet to do your editing, saving your source data in standard Excel format, and write an Excel macro (VBA) to produce the desired JS file output at the press of a button, a bit like pressing the compile button in an IDE. Seriously. It sounds like you want a nice visual editor that can move things around within your array, shift cells up on delete, all the kind of things that Excel is *good* at. The VBA macro you'd need to take the data from the spreadsheet and output it as a JS file with a valid JavaScript array declaration would be trivial, no more than 20 or 30 lines of code, basically a simple nested for loop ought to do it with some initialisation to open a file for writing, etc.

Bearing in mind JavaScript doesn't have multidimensional arrays I'm assuming you want an array of arrays where each child array is the same length and contains objects, and that your desired *output* JS file is something like this (except much bigger):

```
var myObjectArray = [
  [ {id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}, {id:4}  ],
  [ {id:5}, {id:6}, {id:7}, {id:8}  ],
  [ {id:9}, {id:10},{id:11},{id:12} ],
  [ {id:13},{id:14},{id:15},{id:16} ]
];
```

It's easy to produce something like that from Excel.

Comment: Without a doubt, I'm sure there are much better ways to go about this. And it has been quite a learning experience. It was just a little project that has been picked up by my school and scaled way larger than I ever imagined. I'll definitely take a look at VBA and excel. I didn't really want to resort to that since I've yet to do anything similar in my studies, but I guess it will be good to learn. Shouldn't be too difficult. Thanks.

Comment: It's been ages since I last wrote Excel VBA, but I've done export and import type things and I can assure you it's easy. Excel has its own DOM concept so you'll just do something like `Worksheets["myworksheet"].Cells(x,y).Value` in a nested loop. I'm sure you'll figure it out. You might get a better answer to your question if you wait, but either way be sure to come back and accept _some_ answer.